# How Do I Create An Inline Div In An InDesign epub?

Tags: adobe-indesign, epub

I have multiple lines that I want enclosed in a border:

[image]

```
     <p class="Book-Content_Chapters_Body-Text ParaOverride-1">What is the result of running ...
     <p class="Book-Content_Chapters_Body-Text ParaOverride-1">javac DeclarationsInJava.jav....
```

When I set this using the border checkbox in paragraph properties, it displays as expected within InDesign.  However, when I export to epub, there is no border.  It generates a CSS style `ParaOverride-1` in the epub.  The style reads

```
    p.ParaOverride-1 {
          border-color:#000000;
          border-style:solid;
    }
```

If I add `border-width:0.75pt;` to the style, each `p` gets its own block, and I lose the effect of having the `p`'s together in a single rectangle.

[image]

From an HTML/CSS perspective, I believe the way to do this would be to enclose the bordered set of `p`'s into a `div` that had the border styling applied.

My question is, what do I have to do in InDesign to have it generate an epub with a div inserted into a sequence of `p` elements for purposes of putting a single bordering rectangle around those elements?

Comment: Pure *guess*... perhaps an anchored text frame in the primary text frame with a stroke applied to the anchored frame???

Comment: @Scott that sounds exactly right, this is really a question about configuring objects in Indesign.  Does an "anchored text frame" provide a way to establish an anchor in text?  When I create a frame it does not seem to insert an anchor at the insertion point, and maybe I am missing a step.

Comment: Anchored objects within text are anchored to the text. So for example, if you anchor a text frame to "A random line of text." *Where* you anchor it can make a difference... "`a`A random line of text." will behave differently than "A random`a` line of text." which may behave different than "A random line of text.`a`" Sometimes it's about *where* the anchor is placed (by click-dragging the anchor icon).

Comment: This *might* help: https://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1311990&seqNum=4 It's for CS4, but the theories are all still true. And there's this, which is more recent: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/anchored-objects.html

Comment: @Scott yes you nailed with that answer, thank you.  I got the text to flow around it using "above line" positioning on the anchored object.